# Start AVPlayer at a byte offset within a file (Cocoa, Swift)

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

My Mac OS X, sandboxed, application, has a large file within it's bundle.  This file consists of some application specific information appended to the front of a standard MOV file.  I need to provide the bytes of the MOV file to my AVPlayer, but don't want to duplicate the large MOV portion of the file.

Is there a way to simply point the AVPlayer at the first byte of the movie within the file, and tell it to play?

I've looked at NSStreams, FileHandles, and the like, but didn't find a way to turn those into something the AVPlayer would play.

My Fle:

[H----HEADER TO STRIP---HM----------- MOVIE TO PLAY ------------M]

(byte 0)=============(byte 1124)==========================(byte n)